# ApplicationContext.xml and Configuration Class

Tags: spring

Maybe it's weird, but I wonder that if it could possible to use ApplicationContext.xml file and a class that annotated with @Configuration at the same time? and how?

Thanks.

Comment: See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-combining

Comment: XML and Java Config can be mixed without any problems (just remember that XML configuration overrides Java Config).